# Save Multiple Items In Xml With Serialize

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I Save An onject into a xml file with serialize like this:

```
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(tempFilename,FileMode.Create);
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(newType);
        serializer.Serialize(stream,objectname);
```

but with this code i can just enter one item in my xml file and it will be overwrite if i insert new item in it.how can i enter multiple item in my file?Sholud I Use List For it?

Comment: It's hard to answer without knowing the ultimate goal. This is because if you serialize multiple objects to one file one next to each other then the document that will be created will not be a valid Xml document since it will have multiple root elements. Note that this is a valid scenario but I am not sure if this is what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do this quite often.  I usually use a top level class that encapsulates the collection property as a member and has a one to one relationship with the xml file.  Members of that class can be collections or simple attributes etc.

Here is a code snippet for having a collection of custom objects:

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(ElementName = "DeployRuns", Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public class DeployRuns : List<RunDetail>
{
```

And then if you want to encapsulate your collection inside another class which will be serialized, see the bottom property of this class:

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public class DeployDetails
{
   public DeployDetails()
   {
      this.DeployRuns = new DeployRuns();
   }

   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute("sourcePath")]
   public string SourcePath { get; set; }

   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute("archiveDestinationPath")]
   public string ArchiveDestinationPath { get; set; }

   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute("databaseDestinationPath")]
   public string DatabaseDestinationPath { get; set; }

   public DeployRuns DeployRuns { get; set; }
}
```

And to finish off the code example, here is my top level class for this hierarchy:

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(ElementName = "ExecutionHistory", Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public class ExecutionHistory
{
   public ExecutionHistory()
   {
      this.CaptureDetails = new CaptureDetails();
      this.DeployDetails = new DeployDetails();
   }

   [XmlElementAttribute("CaptureDetails", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
   public CaptureDetails CaptureDetails { get; set; }

   [XmlElementAttribute("DeployDetails", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
   public DeployDetails DeployDetails { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to serialize multiple items to a file, then use the `List<T>` data structure.

Note that the type (class) that `T` represents must either be marked with `[XmlRoot]` as a class attribute or implement `IXmlSerializable`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an object of type List and then add as many 'objectname' as you want.  Then pass that List in to be serialized.